# What is the difference between "who" and "users"?

Tags: users, login

As I understand the man pages, `who` simply seems to have more options.

Comment: What about `w`?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 3):

You guessed it, `users`, `who` and `w` fundamentally do the same thing and just differ by their options and the formatting of their output.

Comment: They also differ in what they can use for input.